# Can't access backup hard drive in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, windows-10, backup

I'm trying to backup files in an "internal" 3.5 inch 3 terabyte hard drive using Windows 10.

My computers have external SATA slots, where I can insert these storage devices without having to open my machine to attach power/SATA connectors.

The problem that I am having is that when I try to test my backup (just load the hard drive on another machine to see if I can access everything without any problems) windows isn't able access it. I seem to only be able to access the backup hard drive in the computer that I used to format it.

If I try using it in any other of my computers, the drive is detected, but it's contents don't load. If I try accessing them, windows takes a few seconds to popup the following message:

> W:/ is not accessible. The parameter is incorrect.

Disk management says that the hard drive is't formatted in ntfs and labels the partition as "RAW".

I didn't do any kind of encryption, I just did a normal ntfs format through disk management in windows and used FreeFileSync to copy files that needed to be backed up.

Also, the drive's contents are only recognized and loaded correctly in the external sata slot where it was formatted. I have a separate sata USB dock, and I have the same problem accessing this hard drive's contents (even if the dock is connected to the same machine that formatted the drive).

I have modified the advanced security settings for the drive, and tried making "Everyone" the owner and deleting all groups/usernames and only leaving "SYSTEM" and "Everyone" enabled with full access.

I am also currently doing a full chkdsk (/f /r /x) but I would like to know if there is anything else I might try if chkdsk doesn't find any problems.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the SATA ports on the back of your computer belong to an add-on card in one of your PCIe slots.  This card is either a nice, high-end controller with features you didn't know you had, or it's a cheap pile of off-brand crap that doesn't properly conform to the SATA spec.  It would help to know what make/model this card is.

Either way, the problem is that the card is using some proprietary format and only it can read the drive.  Your only choice is to back up the data and reformat the drive with a different SATA port on a different controller.

---

Here are a some possible technical explanations for why it won't read on other computers:

- The card is a RAID controller and treats all drives as RAID volumes by default.  Other computers wouldn't know how to interpret the RAID config.
- The card has hardware encryption features that are transparent to the user.  Other computers wouldn't be able to read the drive layout.
- The card is using an incorrect geometry for the drive (i.e. using 4Kn sectors on a 512e drive or vice versa).  Other computers would see a corrupt or misaligned partition table.
- The drive contains reserved sectors or is using some other ATA feature that the card is ignoring.  Other computers would see invalid sectors or a different sector count.
- The card is deliberately using a proprietary format as a form of vendor lock-in.